# BTC Bridge not seeing balance in Unisat wallet

Tags: windows, google-chrome-extension, desktop-application

When I connect to the BTC bridge the bridge isn't seeing my balance in my unisat wallet. The address type is Native Segwit and I'm on the testnet. I have 0.00006413 BTC in my testnet wallet.

I'm trying to use the BTC Bridge with my unisat wallet. The bridge isn't seeing my balance in the wallet